# Read access violation in internal class variable

Tags: c++, qt

The code compiles, but when I try to assign a new value to a variable in the **update_Data** method of the **now_Playing** class, it crashes with a variable access error.

[image: Error]

At the same time, if in this method you output data from **new_Data["song_Name"]**, then the data appears, that is, the variable contains data. The error is in the access to **_song_Name**, I cannot even assign to it a simple "value".

In this case, the data is read inside the **now_Playing** class, since QML can access the **_song_Name** variable

As I understand it, this is due to the fact that the call to this function comes from another class, right? How to fix it?

A class that calls a method from another class

```
#ifndef IC_SERVER_H
#define IC_SERVER_H

#include <QJsonObject>
#include <QJsonArray>
#include <QJsonDocument>
#include "httprequesthandler.h"
#include "now_playing.h"

using namespace stefanfrings;

class IC_Server : public HttpRequestHandler {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit IC_Server(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    void service(HttpRequest &request, HttpResponse &response);

signals:

private:
    QByteArray _http_Data;
    QJsonDocument _json_Data;
    QJsonObject _json_Object;

    now_Playing *_NOW_PLAYING;

};

#endif // IC_SERVER_H
```

```
#include "ic_server.h"
#include <QDebug>

IC_Server::IC_Server(QObject *parent) : HttpRequestHandler(parent) {
}

void IC_Server::service(HttpRequest &request, HttpResponse &response) {
    _http_Data = request.getBody();
    _json_Data = QJsonDocument::fromJson(_http_Data);
    _json_Object = _json_Data.object();

    _NOW_PLAYING->update_Data(_json_Object);
}
```

The class that processes data

```
#ifndef NOW_PLAYING_H
#define NOW_PLAYING_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QJsonObject>

class now_Playing : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(QString get_Source_Name READ get_Source_Name NOTIFY media_Changed)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString get_Song_Name READ get_Song_Name NOTIFY media_Changed)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString get_Album_Name READ get_Album_Name NOTIFY media_Changed)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString get_Album_Cover_URL READ get_Album_Cover_URL NOTIFY media_Changed)
    Q_PROPERTY(QList<QString> get_Song_Artists READ get_Song_Artists NOTIFY media_Changed)
    Q_PROPERTY(double get_Song_Duration READ get_Song_Duration NOTIFY media_Changed)
    Q_PROPERTY(double get_Song_Progress READ get_Song_Progress NOTIFY media_Changed)

public:
    explicit now_Playing(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    QString get_Source_Name();
    QString get_Song_Name();
    QString get_Album_Name();
    QString get_Album_Cover_URL();
    QList<QString> get_Song_Artists();
    double get_Song_Duration();
    double get_Song_Progress();
    void update_Data(QJsonObject &new_Data);

signals:
    void media_Changed();

private:
    QJsonObject _now_Playing_Data;
    QString _source_Name = "Spotify";
    QString _song_Name = "Touch Me I'm Going To Scream Part II";
    QString _album_Name = "Evil Urges";
    QString _album_Cover_URL = "http://192.168.1.121:8000/static/now_Playing.jpg";
    QList<QString> _song_Artists = QList<QString>() << QString("My Morning Jacket");
    double _song_Duration = 10000;
    double _song_Progress = 0;
};

#endif // NOW_PLAYING_H
```

```
#include "now_playing.h"

now_Playing::now_Playing(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent) {
}

void now_Playing::update_Data(QJsonObject &new_Data) {
    qDebug() << new_Data;
    qDebug() << new_Data["song_Name"].toString();
    _song_Name = new_Data["song_Name"].toString();
}

QString now_Playing::get_Song_Name() {
    return _song_Name;
}
```

Comment: Maybe your _NOW_PLAYING instance is corrupted/uninitialized? That would cause problems if you tried to access it's members.

Comment: This is an instance of the class. (It seems like I created it correctly, my experience with C ++ is only about 2 weeks). I updated the question and added a header file.

Comment: Can you provide the full error you're referring to when you say "crashes with a variable access error"? Also, it appears that ```void update_Data(QJsonObject &new_Data);``` takes a reference, but maybe you're passing the entire value in when you call it in "IC_Server::Service" here: ```_json_Object = _json_Data.object();

    _NOW_PLAYING->update_Data(_json_Object);```. Try adding an ampersand in front of the argument in that call. I would assume your compiler would catch that though, so I'm not sure.

Comment: Added error screenshot. The _json_Object is passed to the update_Data method ok, because I can access the data in the _json_Object, this data is output to qDebug() normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_NOW_PLAYING` never initialized. Initialize it in constructor.

Create a new one:

```
IC_Server::IC_Server(QObject *parent) 
    : HttpRequestHandler(parent),
      _NOW_PLAYING(new now_Playing(this))
{}
```

Or share a created one:

```
IC_Server::IC_Server(now_Playing* nowPlaying, QObject *parent) 
    : HttpRequestHandler(parent),
      _NOW_PLAYING(nowPlaying)
{
    // assign null to _NOW_PLAYING when deleted.
    if (_NOW_PLAYING)
        connect(_NOW_PLAYING, &QObject::destroyed, [&](){_NOW_PLAYING = nullptr;});
}

void IC_Server::service(HttpRequest &request, HttpResponse &response) {
    _http_Data = request.getBody();
    _json_Data = QJsonDocument::fromJson(_http_Data);
    _json_Object = _json_Data.object();

    if (_NOW_PLAYING) // if _NOW_PLAYING is still alive
        _NOW_PLAYING->update_Data(_json_Object);
}
```

Also signals must called to notify properties about change.

```
void now_Playing::update_Data(QJsonObject &new_Data) {
    _song_Name = new_Data["song_Name"].toString();
    emit media_Changed();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the variable is LIKE to be updated, but I don't see any changes in qml, although I call the media_Changed() signal, and if a timer is created in the now_Playing class and some other variable is updated, the data in qml is updated normally. Could it be that a new instance of _song_Name is being created?

Comment: I think what you see in qml is another instance of `now_Playing`. If that is the case pass `now_Playing*` as parameter to `IC_Server` constructor and initialize `_NOW_PLAYING` by parameter.

Comment: I just updated the answer with a constructor that takes `now_Playing*` as parameter.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot, everything works!

Comment: Glad it worked, I just thought `_NOW_PLAYING` might die before `IC_Server`. So I added  availability check for  `_NOW_PLAYING` against it's die-bility. No more edits, promise ;P